# UIStackView losing constraints when using custom XIBs

Tags: ios, swift

I am attempting to dynamically add views to a `UIStackView`.

I have a `XIB` with a full screen `UIStackView` within. I then have some views - labels and text field/ text views.

The idea here is that I have a class that manages these individual views and that class has it's own `XIB` file for the layout.

So the class that handles the outermost `UIStackView` will grab the layout from the individual classes and add it as a subview to the `UIStackView`.

When attempting to do this, the view appears squashed and not in keeping with the original constraints.

I could offer code but I will explain the constraints.

The outer `UIStackView` is just stretched as full screen with distribution fill and equal spacing.

An example of an 'inner' view would be a label. I have an individual `XIB` file that holds a `UIView` and then a `Label` within that. The label is pinned to the center of the `UIView`.

I believe the issue lies with adding custom XIBs to an existing `UIStackView`. I'm not sure how much more information I give/ is required but I suspect there is something I am missing that someone may spot straight away from the information given.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UIStackView does exactly what you are asking it to do.  If the constraints are setup so the UIStackView fills in the entire screen, then you need to provide content, that when it is equally divided on the screen, has the expected layout, each of the view inserted will be resized to be equally sized.

If you do not know how many views are going to be used, but you need each of your views to take their respective aspect ratio on the screen, then you can use the "Fill Proportionally" option.  The UIStackView will add the height of every view, then divide its own height and distribute it proportionally to each view.  If you add too many views this too will start to squash your views.

To avoid these kinds of issues, you may wish to put your UIStackView inside of a UIScrollView.  You then setup a constraint with very very low priority to set the UIStackView height to 0, as you insert your views the UIStackView will automatically be resized to fit in the different views.

Good luck!

Comment: I think it's the last bit that is going to get this over the line. It seems to work correctly except the height of the StackView. I've been building Android apps for years so this is a bit of a different way of doing this! I'll give it a go, thanks.